# how to select brushX or brushY based on mouse direction in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In **d3.js** **v4**, I am trying to implement brush (to zoom selected area) for a line chart. I want the brush in X or Y direction to be selected based on the direction the mouse moves first.

If the mouse moves to left or right, brushX needs to be invoked and if mouse moves first in top or bottom direction, brushY needs to be invoked.

Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented above feature as per my requirements.

Here is the code
https://bl.ocks.org/Shravya-Siluveru/d958edfcbd6333e1a07054c15060ebd9/a6907c80f62202136ec2201cf15b776374e27732